# SKStore​Review​Controller With Xcode 11

Tags: objective-c, xcode, skstorereviewcontroller

We have the StoreKit framework in our iOS (Obj-C) project so that our app will link because we use SKStore​Review​Controller.

Xcode 11 apparently thinks that since we have the StoreKit framework in our project, we must have In-App Purchase capability; we do not nor do we want it.

We get errors when building on the command-line:

With StoreKit framework in our project:

```
"Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "xxxx xxxx Ad Hoc Dist Profile" doesn't support the In-App Purchase capability."
```

Without StoreKit framework:

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreReviewController", referenced from: ..."
```

Building in Xcode IDE **with** the StoreKit framework in the project, the app builds and links, but fails to run on a device (presumably because of the code signing error).

It seems odd that I haven't heard much about this happening to other devs.
Are we doing something wrong?  Xcode 10 and previous builds fine.

Comment: It appears this is being caused by us using a wildcard AppId and an "iOS Distribution" profile instead of the newer Apple "Distribution" profile ("For use in Xcode 11 or later").